# Managed Bootstrapper Application "Failed to resolve source for file"

Tags: wix

Before I started creating my own custom Managed Bootstrapper Application, I was using the existing Fragment below with no issues, i.e. it would download the .msi from the internet if the local file was not found. Now when I try to execute the MBA I get the error below in the log file.

[Environment]
WiX 3.7, Visual Studio 2012, x64

[Bundle.wxs]

> `<PackageGroupRef Id="ReportViewer"/>`

[Fragment.wxs]

```
<PackageGroup Id="ReportViewer">
  <MsiPackage DisplayName="Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime"
              Cache="no" Compressed="no" ForcePerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
              SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\ReportViewer\ReportViewer.msi"
              DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217022"
              InstallCondition="(VersionNT >= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.0)"/>
</PackageGroup>
```

[Log]

> [14:42]i101: Detected package: ReportViewer.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
>
> [14:54]i201: Planned package: ReportViewer.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
>
> [15:00]w343: Prompt for source of package: ReportViewer.msi, payload: ReportViewer.msi, path: E:\ReportViewer.msi
> [15:00]e054: Failed to resolve source for file: E:\ReportViewer.msi, error: 0x80070002.
> [15:00]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed while prompting for source (original path 'E:\ReportViewer.msi').
> [15:00]e313: Failed to acquire payload: ReportViewer.msi to working path: C:\Users\POS1User\AppData\Local\Temp{416b9117-e1b4-4518-b13d-eb5416da8794}\ReportViewer.msi, error: 0x80070002.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a package is not present locally, the Burn engine asks your bootstrapper application to deal with the ResolveSource call. As explained in [this other Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14653902/19818), you should add your own event handler for the ResolveSource event. You can simply instruct Burn to download the package for you:

```cs
this.Bootstrapper.ResolveSource += OnResolveSource;

...

private void OnResolveSource(object sender, ResolveSourceEventArgs e)
    if (!File.Exists(e.LocalSource) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.DownloadSource))
        e.Result = Result.Download;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the `OnResolveSource` method is never fired (debug breakpoint never gets there)

Comment: I suggest double-checking this route. Inspecting [apply.cpp](http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/burn/engine/apply.cpp) shows that between the `w343` and `e054` log lines is the call to `pUX->pUserExperience->OnResolveSource`, so your BA should be receiving this event.

Comment: i have one important question, why WIX documentation is simply not mentioning this? I was fighting with this last couple of days.... thank you so much for this