# Prompt for source of container: WixAttachedContainer Problem

Tags: c#, windows-installer, wix3.11

Good day everyone,

While working with Wix I am having a hard time solving the following error message:
Prompt for source of container: WixAttachedContainer

**The scenario:**

- We have a setup project with the default Wix template that acts as a bundle for several packages, called MyBundle.exe.
- We have a managed bootstrapper application wix exe with WPF and C# that acts as a standalone installer, but this needs to be included in the bundle stated above, called MyApp.exe.
- MyApp.exe gets installed correctly when installing MyBundle.exe.
- When uninstalling MyBundle.exe and having a DetectCondition to uninstall MyApp.exe. MyApp.exe gets removed correctly.

**The Problem:**

- There is a scenario where MyBundle.exe will get removed but has to leave MyApp.exe installed behind.
- After removing MyBundle.exe, and trying to remove MyApp.exe I get the following error in the log:
  Prompt for source of container: WixAttachedContainer, path: "Path_To_EXE"

If I install MyApp.exe as a standalone and uninstall it, everything works just fine.
If I install MyBundle.exe (MyApp.exe included in MyBundle.exe) and uninstall MyApp.exe before removing MyBundle.exe, this works fine as well.

I have read the logs of MyApp.exe where the error comes up and I found that MyApp.exe is trying to reach the cache folder of MyBundle.exe 
**Prompt for source of container: WixAttachedContainer, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{Bundle_GUID}\Dependencies\MyApp.exe**
But at this point, that folder is no more on the system.

The configuration of the ExePackage in MyBundle.exe is as follows:

```
<ExePackage Id="MyApp_Package"
            Description="MyApp Package"
            DisplayName="MyApp Package"
            SourceFile="My_Path_To_Package"
            Compressed="yes"
            Permanent="yes"
            PerMachine="yes"
            Vital="yes"
            Cache="yes">
</ExePackage>
```

I have tried several combinations of the tags Permanent, Cache, but still to no effect.

I have tried already hooking up to the ResolveSource method inside the C# code on MyApp.exe following instructions like this:
[Managed Bootstrapper Application "Failed to resolve source for file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969167/managed-bootstrapper-application-failed-to-resolve-source-for-file) but to no success.

Can any of you point me in the correct direction?

UPDATE: Both MyBundle.exe and MyApp.exe, as well as the msi included are signed using signtool.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you signing your bootstrapper?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter, Yes, the bootstrapper is being signed.

Comment: How are you signing it?  Are you using insignia or signtool?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "insignia"

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/insignia.html

It's not enough to just use signtool to sign the boostrapper EXE.  The bundle inside it needs to be signed also.

Comment: My bad, i forgot to comment that MyBundle.exe and MyApp.exe and the msi included are signed. Question has been updated.